# Projective geometry tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Would it make sense to merge the tag [projective-plane](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/projective-plane) and [projective-space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/projective-space) into [projective-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/projective-geometry)?  It doesn't seem useful to have to search for each of these separately.

Comment: I think the small tag [tag:projective-plane] (only 4) should very likely be removed (maby synonym or merge into [tag:projective-geometry]) For the two other larger ones, I do not know.

Comment: I think both should be merged.  However, I think some of the questions tagged with projective-space could benefit from a weighted-projective-space tag.

Comment: There are non-Desarguesian projective planes, and the projective space tag would not always be appropriate for these. So having both tags is useful. (Potentially at least, since very few questions on this topic have been posed.)

Comment: @Godsil: um, but I'd like to keep only [projective-geometry], not space.

Comment: I am only arguing that there are grounds for keeping the projective-plane tag. It seems very reasonable to drop the projective-space tag in favour of the projective-geometry tag.

Comment: @Godsil: ok, but in that case could projective-plane be a sub-tag of projective-geometry?  Or does the 5-tag limit stop that?

Comment: I know nothing about 5-tag limits. The sub-tag issue itself could be argued both ways. To be consistent I would have to say that it should not be a sub-tag, but consistency is over-rated.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil does what you say apply to any of the questions *currently* tagged (there are only four so you might check) [tag:projective-plane]. I think (but could be wrong) it does not. So, the point seems somewhat moot. Since if there is no tag-wiki (which is true) there is hardly any notion of 'having a tag' or not.  Put differently, do you see an issue with *these four questions* being *retagged* projective-geometry?

Comment: I do not see any issue with retagging those four questions.